# MySQL Prefix Match with limit not returning results ordered by primary key ASC

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization

I've created a table with an AI primary index and inserted the rows into it in a specific order, according to an internal weight function.

Now I'm doing a query

```
SELECT smtng FROM tbl WHERE var LIKE 'query%' LIMIT 5
```

I was under the assumption that MySQL will perform the search for the first 5 matches, and because I've inserted them according to an internal weight function, I will get the TOP5 (assuming this is a read-only table). However, it doesn't return those. **Why?**

btw I've noticed that when using a full-text index I do get the expected result.

Comment: If the PK is auto increment, then your query produces results based on the natural insertion order. Order the results by the "order" calculated by that weight function (I'm assuming you have some sort of a column that holds that result).

Comment: The whole procedure was to avoid the ORDER BY weight which made the query slower. If he produces the results based on the natural insertion order, why doesn't he return the first 5?? Will it be much easier for him to order in this case?

Comment: It'd be easier if you posted your table structure and explained the problem in detail. The issue here is that you're probably not optimizing the query very well and you're misusing the way inserting and querying works.

Comment: var is varchar(255) with index on it. PK is AI and insertion was done after sorting the inserted data according to a weight int, which is also present in the table.